# How to track the permissions given by multiple TFS Admins?

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2015 U3, and we are totally of 2 Admins.

We have given permissions to many users and would like to track who is given accesses to whom? and what time we have provided access?

Is there any way to find out the log?

Thanks,
Sat

Answer (score 0):

No, we can only get the information on who managed the permissions from **Activity Log**, but can not track giving the accesses to whom. (The related records can not be found even in the database)

To check the **Activity Log**.

1. Go to http://server:8080/tfs/_oi
2. Select the specific Collection, enter the specific Account (Admin
   user account) in `Identity Name` area to filter the Activity log.
3. Find the command `ApiSecurity.ManagePermissions` -> `Show Details`

[image]